# How do SE sites prevent text formatting/encoding errors from database results?

Tags: support, markdown, technology

Stack Exchange sites display the text of questions and answers nicely (i.e. with formatting) from their databases.  What technologies are used to display the formatted text?  I program with C#; can the same results be achieved with that language?

Comment: What you mean to ask is "Which technologies were used to write stackoverflow.com?" ?

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow uses an own version of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). I have started using [Markdown.NET](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/markdown_announced.aspx) for a couple of my own projects.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [What was SO built with](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/).